# Typescript Set collection field inside object before HTTP POST

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Before trying to POST an Object (User), I got this error when composing it like this:

Here is my model class:

```
export class User {
userRoles:  Set<UserRole>;
id: number;
}
```

In my TS I put:

```
const newUser = new User();
var userRoleList = new Set<UserRole>();

var iterator = userRoleList .values();
newUser.userRoles=  Array.from(iterator);
```

I got this error:

> error TS2740: Type 'UserRole[]' is missing the following properties
> from type 'Set': add, clear, delete, has, and 2 more.
> newUser.userRoles=  Array.from(iterator);

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You're setting your `User.userRoles` type to `Set<UserRole>` but in your code, `newUser.userRoles=  Array`, you're making it an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a value of type Array to the property of a class with the type Set. Change your class declaration to:

`export class User { userRoles: UserRole[]; id: number; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the array to the `Set` constructor :

```
const newUser = new User();
var userRoleList = new Set<UserRole>();

var iterator = userRoleList .values();
newUser.userRoles=  new Set(Array.from(iterator));
```

Done in a more elegant way:

```
const newUser = new User();
const userRoleList = new Set<UserRole>();
newUser.userRoles=  new Set([...userRoleList .values()]);
```

Comment: I've tried your answer but userRoleList goes epmty in my http POST playload even it's a Set and in my user model it's a Set too and it already set before sending my request